# retrofit enqueue stop and exit suddenly

Tags: android, codeigniter, centos, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit enqueue to call CodeIgniter Restful API and get subscription message then move to next screen.

inside subscription API method I'm calling SMS and Email services.
if I use only SMS or Email during subscription then program works fine and enqueue OnResponse method being executed. BUT if I use both SMS and Email in same subscription function then enqueue call will exit without executing OnResponse or OnFailure.

I have tried to increase max_execution_time and max_input_time but without success. I don't know what the reason cause my application to exit without executing OnResponse/ OnFailure methods.

also I couldn't trace logs to know the issue because OnFailure is not executed.

I'm using Centos 8 and Apache as web server.

here is the code in CodeIgniter Restful API that insert user to database, then send SMS & email:

```
$data['user_name']='essa';
$mobnumber = $this->trim_number($data["phone"]);

$data['otp'] = $this->random_number();
$data['otp_status'] = '0';

$this->services_model->insert_data('subscribers',$data);
$id = $this->db->insert_id();

$this->sendsms($mobnumber ,$data['otp']);

$template_data['user_name']  = $data['username'];
$template_data['userid']  = base64_encode($id);
      $em_message = $this->parser->parse("subscription.html", $template_data, TRUE);
      $email_result = send_mail($data['email'],'registration',$em_message);
      
      $result = ["status"=>1,"message"=>'Registration successful'];
      $this->response($result,REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
```

and here is my Retrofit.enqueue code:

```
retrofitCall .enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response)
            {
                if (response.isSuccessful())
                {
    
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());

                        int status = jsonObject.getInt("status");
                        String message  = jsonObject.getString("message");
                        showToast(message);

                        Intent i = new Intent(Welcome.this, Welcome.class);
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        i.putExtra("message",message);
                        startActivity(i);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("retrofiError",t.toString());
            }
        });
```